# NSTimer in NSOperation main method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4

I want to set up a timer in  `-(void) main {}` method of a NSOperation subclass. However, I the timer doesn't fire. I tried `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];` with no success. Am I missing smth?

[EDIT] Will this run the timer on the main thread or on NSOperation's thread? (guessing NSOperation, but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what need to be done to start the timer. I'll put it here if anyone ever needs it:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

However, I'm still not sure if this will run in the NSOperation's thread.

Comment: You can always find out. In the method called by the timer, log the output of `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: Combining run loops and timers in this fashion is a really poor design pattern.  That will end up blocking the operation queue and can quite easily starve the concurrency subsystem for threads (or cause the system to spawn a ton of threads).

Comment: @bbum I see, however, if I want to use a timer in a NSOperation, is there another way. Or you are saying that operations and timers should never be combined?

Comment: Mixing the two should be avoided;   there is generally going to be a better way.  Any time you have a timer, that is effectively a linear break in execution and, ideally, should not be blocking a queue or otherwise consuming system resources (beyond the passive timer maintained in the run loop).

Comment: @bbum - I don't think that is always the case.  If you are performing a memory heavy operation and only want one operation to execute at a time, then you want the queue to stop executing until the operation is complete.  Whether you poll some state variable with a timer to determine if the operation should complete or you listen for a notification, you are still blocking the queue (which is what you want) until the operation completes.  This becomes a much worse idea if you allow lots of operations to execute concurrently and don't implement a "timeout" or "max tries" error condition

Comment: @tony  While conceptually correct, you absolutely *do not* want to block a queue or run loop as a means of throttling execution.  It can easily lead to deadlock, timer pileup (a slew of timers filing all at once), and/or task starvation.  Use a semaphore or other scheduling primitive to control the # of items enqueued.

Answer (score 2):

I find that it is sometimes useful to wrap an NSOperation around a method that is fired by a timer, like you are doing, to take advantage of the dependencies, cancellation, and other features provided by the operations queue. It is however not usually necessary for the timer to run in a separate thread, nor is it usually necessary for the method that the timer invokes to be running in a background thread. In fact, most of the time it *shouldn't* run in a background thread because the method updates the UI. If this is true for you too a setup like this should work:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TimerOperation : NSOperation {
@private
    NSTimer* _timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isExecuting;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isFinished;

@end
```

(Add in your own state, custom constructor, etc.).

```
@implementation TimerOperation

@synthesize isExecuting = _executing;
@synthesize isFinished  = _finished;

- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _executing = NO;
        _finished  = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [_timer release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL) isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}

- (void) finish {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = NO;
    _finished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (void) start {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    } else {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(main) 
                               withObject:nil 
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        _executing = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
}

- (void) timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        // Whatever you want to do when the timer fires
    }
}

- (void) main {
    _timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                             userInfo:nil 
                                              repeats:YES] retain];
}

- (void) cancel {
    [_timer invalidate];
    [super cancel];
}

@end
```

Of course, if the main thread is blocked (for instance, because of a long database save) you will not see the timer firing, but most of the time this works fine.

You can use the same setup to deal with asynchronous APIs inside NSOperations.

Comment: Why do you maintain a reference to the timer in this example?

Comment: So that we can call [_timer invalidate] in cancel.